# Managed apps with named credentials-Callback Url issues

Tags: community

We are developing a CTI App. For phone related make call/End call we are making external API Calls to the phone service provider. I have created a named credential with Auth provider with details for the external application and included it in our managed package.

Now, because the URL is different for each of our clients, we must create a new Named Credential in each installed org - we can't put it into the managed package. Also, since Auth. Providers can't be included in managed packages, we must create a new Auth. Provider in each installed org. The Auth. Provider is using phone service provider OAuth authentication and is saved with a Callback URL which Salesforce generates. When I tested this in the org where I created the managed package, I had to copy that generated Callback URL into the Callback URL list of my external client application. This raises a problem:

So my question: should each subscriber create their own app in the external application and create Auth Provider with the client Id and client secret and update the callback URL in the external application themselves.is there any other workaround to reduce the work on the subscriber side.

Thanks in advance for any help/insight.